# Problema con react-big-calendar: Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Tengo problema con react-big-calendar.
Me sale un error, que no se pudo importar "react-big-calendar/libs/css/react-big-calendar.css" desde "src\calendar\pages\CalendarPage.jsx" y me pregunta si este archivo existe.
Probé a instalarlo con npm install --save react-big-calendar --legacy-peer-deps, después de instalarlo con npm install --save react-big-calendar y npm i react-big-calendar y que no funcionara ninguna.
Me pregunta si no está el archivo y si esta en package.json, entonces no entiendo que pasa.

Esto es lo que me sale:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "react-big-calendar/libs/css/react-big-calendar.css" from "src\calendar\pages\CalendarPage.jsx". Does the file exist?
C:/Users/maria/Documents/React/10-calendar/src/calendar/pages/CalendarPage.jsx:3:7
18 |  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
19 |  import { Calendar } from "react-big-calendar";
20 |  import "react-big-calendar/libs/css/react-big-calendar.css";
   |          ^
21 |  import { NavBar, CalendarEvent, CalendarModal, FabAddNew, FabDelete } from "../";
22 |  import { localizer, getMessagesES } from "../../helpers";
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, puedes empezar revisando si tus rutas estan bien escritas por ejemplo aquí `src\calendar\pages\CalendarPage.jsx`, puede que algún caracater este mal escrito o que estes direccionando al directorio equivocado, uno arriba o abajo